# iframe in table - cant overlay

Tags: html, css

This is my scenario

```
<div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="innerDiv">
                            This div contains background image</div>
                        <iframe></iframe>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="thirdTR">
                    <td>
                        <%--i have table here with a div that has a background image--%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Now when i try to have the "innerDiv" over the "thirdTR" along with the iframe, the div goes behind the "thirdTR". I even tried setting the zindex as high as possible. Can anyone please help me?

Regards,
Lakxman Kumar C

Edited: This is the css that i have for the innerDiv

```
position:absolute;
z-index:999
```

Comment: please post all css-ruels applied to any of your elements, otherwise it's very hard to say whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you can't lay a div over an iframe, simply impossible. you'll have to find a workaround (maybe using a div and AJAX to replace the iframe... or changing your layout so you don't need something above the frame)

Comment: thanks for the update oezi. But i'm even not possible to overlay the div over the "thirdTR". Is there any restrictions for that also? Please correct me if im wrong anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't allowed to put things over iframes in the html standard. If you could, people could hide links on other pages and phish more easily etc.